# Redshift returns The server (version 8.0) does not support altering default privileges

Tags: amazon-redshift, psql

I am trying to drop a user from redshift:

```
DROP USER xx;
```

I get:

```
[2021-03-01 14:00:39] [2BP01][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: user "xx" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
[2021-03-01 14:00:39] Details:
[2021-03-01 14:00:39] owner of default privileges on new relations belonging to user xx;
```

I already removed it from the group:

```
ALTER GROUP a DROP USER xx;
```

I run:

```
select *
from pg_user
LEFT JOIN pg_group ON pg_user.usesysid = ANY(pg_group.grolist)
order by 1;
```

And it returns: `xx,109,false,false,false,********,,,,,`

Also run:

```
revoke create,usage on schema public from xx;
revoke all privileges on schema public from xx;
```

Then run this:

```
 SELECT
distinct s.schemaname,
    u.usename,
    --'REVOKE ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA '+s.schemaname+' FROM ronnylopez;',
    has_schema_privilege(u.usename,s.schemaname,'create') AS user_has_select_permission,
    has_schema_privilege(u.usename,s.schemaname,'usage') AS user_has_usage_permission
FROM
    pg_user u
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT schemaname FROM pg_tables) s
WHERE
    user_has_select_permission=True
  and u.usename = 'xx';
```

And it returns only one row:

```
public,xx,true,true
```

If i run the default acl:

```
select * from pg_default_acl where defacluser= 109;

109,0,r,"{group admins=arwdRxt/xx,xx=arwdRxt/xx}"
```

To drop these i pretend to use `\ddp` using `psql` but i get:

```
The server (version 8.0) does not support altering default privileges.
```

So i'm stuck on here and not able to drop the user....

Answer (score 0):

You can use the view [`v_generate_user_grant_revoke_ddl` provided on GitHub](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_generate_user_grant_revoke_ddl.sql) to generate all of the `REVOKE` statements needed to allow the `DROP USER` to complete.

The `ddl` column provides the generated SQL

```sql
SELECT ddl
FROM v_generate_user_grant_revoke_ddl
WHERE grantee = 'useriwanttodrop';
```

Run the generated SQL and then drop the user. May require superuser permission.

```sql
--Generated
SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION master;
REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE mydb FROM useriwanttodrop;
RESET SESSION AUTHORIZATION;
--Drop
DROP USER useriwanttodrop;
```